# What's with this DigiD code I hear about?

Tags: netherlands, identification, online-resources

I've been living in the Netherlands for a while. I've registered with the IND, I have a valid residence permit, I have a BSN number, health insurance - everything.

Now someone tells me there's something called "DigiD" and that I should have gotten one. Well, should I have? That is, do I really need something that I've never used or been asked for? Which I wasn't given during my initial pass through the Dutch bureaucracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Just get it, you might need it later.

[DigiD](https://digid.nl/) is an access verification system common to many Dutch government websites. It is used both for one-factor authentication (user id + password) or for [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) (user id + password, then a code to be received by SMS and repeated).

Many government services are rendered without involving authenticated access to government websites. Specifically, applying for a BSN, registering home address changes, applying for the 30% tax ruling, and other such procedures don't require it - you download some publicly-available form and mail it; or you must present yourself in some office.

But other government/government-related services do require it - at least for availing yourself of them online. Examples: The [Studielink](http://info.studielink.nl/en/studenten/Pages/Default.aspx) website which allows for enrolling in various educational institutions. The Dutch government portal for information regarding government services, [overheid.nl](https://www.overheid.nl/english/), the ["Employee Insurance Agency", UWV](https://www.uwv.nl/overuwv/english/about-us-executive-board-organization/detail/about-us), where you [apply online for unemployment benefits](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/12120/7110), etc.
(Even [some medical insurance companies](https://www.zorgenzekerheid.nl/service-en-contact/service/declareren/indienen.htm) are switching their logins to DigiD).

(I don't quite have a good list of examples; you're welcome to edit some into this answer.)

You should probably get it now rather than later, because there's a procedure of sending an authentication code to your registered address, i.e. the registration isn't made purely online.

To get your DigiD, go [here](https://www.digid.nl/index.php?id=73&L=1.). It takes a few days for them to send you an activation code by post, i.e. you don't get the code immediately on registering there.